# Telerik RadGridView grouping

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, radgridview

I have `RadGridView`  in my `Winforms` application and i want to group my files so i use this:

```
RadGridView radGridView1;
DataTable table = null;

radGridView1.ShowColumnHeaders = false;
radGridView1.ShowGroupPanel = false;
radGridView1.ShowRowHeaderColumn = false;
radGridView1.AllowAddNewRow = false;
radGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
radGridView1.GroupDescriptors.Add(new Telerik.WinControls.Data.GroupDescriptor("File"));

private void AddFile(string file)
{
    table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Protocol", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Property Value1", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add("File size:", "", file);
    table.Rows.Add("File duration:", "",  file);
    table.Rows.Add("Creation time:", "", file);
    radGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

My problem is that after the first file was chosen and added so in the next file - nothing happen and i think it's because the table i already have same  A column names.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the `DataTable` and do the `Column.Add()` once, Right now you're creating a new table for every file and you replace the old table every time.

It should look like this:

```
RadGridView radGridView1;
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Protocol", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Property Value1", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("File", typeof(string));

radGridView1.ShowColumnHeaders = false;
radGridView1.ShowGroupPanel = false;
radGridView1.ShowRowHeaderColumn = false;
radGridView1.AllowAddNewRow = false;
radGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
radGridView1.GroupDescriptors.Add(new Telerik.WinControls.Data.GroupDescriptor("File"));
radGridView1.DataSource = table;

private void AddFile(string file)
{
    table.Rows.Add("File size:", "", file);
    table.Rows.Add("File duration:", "",  file);
    table.Rows.Add("Creation time:", "", file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks now it's working, BTW can i see my files adding "ongoing" ? cause right now i only can see all the files that added in one time (in case of choosing many files)